# For a set that belongs to Z need to find A-B and (A ∧ B) V B

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

if A = {n | n ∈ Z and n ≤ 10}

and B = {0,1,6,7,9}

I need to find A-B and (A ∧ B) V B but unable to determine if set A should be {1....10} or {...-1,0,....}

Though I think it should be the latter since Z is just integers and not positive integers

So should A-B be {...-3,-2,-1,2,3,4,5,8,10}
and (A ∧ B) V B = {0,1,6,7,9}

Comment: Exactly , you solved right.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It's an interesting exercise to prove $(A \cup B) \cap B \equiv B$ for all sets $A$ and $B$, and also $(A \cap B) \cup B \equiv B$. These are sometimes known as the **absorption laws**.